# Strange "pause" in video after concatenation of two mp4 videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am concatenating two mp4 videos. The problem is that first video (intro.mp4) lasts 5 seconds, second video (output.mp4) lasts 2 seconds and video created by concatenating them lasts 9 seconds (and should last 5+2 = 7 seconds). In final.mp4 video the last frame from first video (intro.mp4) i shown for additional 2 seconds before second video (output.mp4) is played. It looks like a lag when watching video. What I am doing wrong?

list.txt:

```
file 'data/intro.mp4'
file 'output.mp4'
```

command:

```
./bin/ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a6a80e600] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1296 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 1163 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 11988 tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 133 kb/s
[mp4 @ 0x7f8a6c006a00] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x7f8a6c006a00] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'final.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 960x540, q=2-31, 1163 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 11988 tbn, 11988 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 133 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f8a6a80e600] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
frame=  258 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     997kB time=00:00:09.84 bitrate= 829.5kbits/s    
video:897kB audio:93kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.634306%
```

Comment: Are the videos definitely encoded the same way - same video and audio codecs within the mp4 files? ffmpeg mp4 concat the way you are using it only works properly if this is the case, I think.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well.  Files are two successive mpg's from the same camera, seconds apart.  I'm quite sure they're both the same codecs and format.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with 2 mpg files.  I was using this command:

ffmpeg -i "concat:foo.mpg|bar.mpg|" -c copy out.mpg

I found this link:

https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-March/013933.html

which suggested setting the duration explicitly with the duration directive in an input file, i.e. a file looking like this:

```
file foo.mpg
duration 6
file bar.mpg
duration 4.5
```

where the numbers are in seconds.

Oddly, when I switched to using an input list from a file, the problem went away even without setting the duration. Very odd.  I double checked and consistently got the pause with the command line list and none with the file list in a text file..  Obviously that's not working for you, as you've already got an input list file, but the duration trick might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when my video files lenght was not just in seconds but in milliseconds as well. The little pause is to stretch the last frame till it fill out that second.